# How to select features based on layer intersection on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, select-by-location

At work I have to trace some polygons over some points of a point layer and then select these points by using "Select By Location" feature that comes with ArcGIS - like this:
[image]

So, with this I can select the points that I've traced the polygons and save them to a new layer. Is there a way to do this on QGIS? I'm not very familiar to this selection feature in QGIS, only to selecting by an attribute table.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the [`select by location` tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisselectbylocation)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can, see the pic for more details

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @xerxes If answer helped you solve you problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems know that problem was resolved.